# Questions about Symfony 2 service container parameters

Tags: symfony

**1. Passing parameters into the service?**
If not already defined in the services.xml (or yaml), is the only way to pass parameter(s) into service is:

```
$container->setParameter('loader', $loader);
$container->get('myservice');
```

I suppose this way loader will be available to ALL services, not just "myservice"?

**2. Passing an array of objects into the service?**
The Template/DelegatingEngine class takes an array of engine object into the constructor, and I dont know how should I define that in the xml file:

```
public function __construct(array $engines = array())
    {
        $this->engines = array();
        foreach ($engines as $engine) {
            $this->addEngine($engine);
        }
    }
```

What should I put into the

```
<service id="myCustomeFramework.TemplateEngine" class="path\to\DelegateEngine" scope="prototype">
            <argument>how can i pass an array of engines here?</argument>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1**

Yes, it will be available for all services that uses that parameter and that are called after setting the parameter.

**Answer 2**

For passing an array as an argument to a service using xml you have to do it in this way:

```
<service id="myCustomeFramework.TemplateEngine" class="path\to\DelegateEngine" scope="prototype">
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="key">value</argument>
        <argument key="key">value</argument>
        <argument key="key">value</argument>
    </argument>
</service>
```

Comment: Thank you artberri, since <argument key="key">value</argument> is supposed to pass in an engine object, what should I put in the value field?

Comment: @mr1031011 , do you find the solution please?

Comment: @VidyVideni Perhaps you can either pass as a service or use a factory to do it?